# nodejs socket.io emit is not executed

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've got the problem that the second emit() in the following code (I have picked the important part if there is more needed just ask), which is sending a "stateChange"-Event, seems not to be executed. The "ID"-Event is received by the Server.

```
this.socket = io.connect('...');
this.socket.emit("ID", {canvasID: this.ID});

this.socket.on(PLACE_BUBBLE, function(data){
    var node = uCanvas.placeBubble(data.x1, data.y1);
    this.socket.emit("stateChange",
        {action : PLACE_BUBBLE, canvasID : this.ID, nodeID : node.nodeID, x : node.x, y : node.y});
});
```

The server is looking like this:

```
socketio.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("ID", function(data){
       ...
    });
    socket.on("stateChange", function(data){
       ...
    });
});
```

placeBubble() is executed but there is simply no information send back to the server.

/solved: Problem was "this" in this.socket.emit which should be uCanvas.socket.emit(). This was the object holding the socket.

Comment: Add that as an answer and mark it as such - that will clear this as an unanswered question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Problem was "this" in this.socket.emit which should be uCanvas.socket.emit(). This was the object holding the socket.